# Clarification on the definition of a basis.

Tags: linear-algebra

So we came upon a theorem in our Linear Algebra course, and it says:

Let $\dim(\textsf{V}) = n$, where $n > 0$:

$(\textrm{i})$ A subset $\beta$ of $\textsf{V}$ is a basis if and only if $|\beta| = n$ and $\beta$ is linearly independent.

$(\textrm{ii})$ A subset $\beta$ of $\textsf{V}$ is a basis if and only if $|\beta| = n$ and $\beta$ spans $\textsf{V}$.

Obviously, we can use whichever is more useful for what we're trying to prove.
However, I'm finding this hard to accept. Given 
$$\operatorname{span} \{(2, 1, 3, 1), (1, 2, 0, 1), (-1, 1, -3, 0)\}$$
the dimension is $2$ and a basis is $\{(2, 1, 3, 1), (1, 2, 0, 1)\}$.

But $\{(1, -1, 1, 0), (0, 0, 0, 1)\}$ is also linearly independent with dimension $2$, but it doesn't span the original set, so it can't be a basis.

My initial rationalization is that 
$$\operatorname{span}\{(1, -1, 1, 0), (0, 0, 0, 1)\}$$
is not a subspace of $\operatorname{span}\{(2, 1, 3, 1), (1, 2, 0, 1), (-1, 1, -3, 0)\}$. Is my reasoning correct, or am I missing something here?

Comment: Did you mean to say that (1,-1,1,0) and (0,0,0,1) are *linearly independent*?  Note that these two vectors aren't a subset of the $V$ that you defined in the previous paragraph, so the definition isn't applicable to them.

Comment: Yes, sorry, independent. I'll edit that. Also, yes, I meant the first span as the V in this case. And yes, thank you! This has been confusing me. That it's not a subset makes the clearest sense. Nice to have that cleared up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That’s basically correct. Elements of a basis of a vector space $V$ are necessarily elements of $V$. This is a condition in the quoted theorem: “A **subset** $B$ of $V$...” Note, though, that the only condition is that $B$ be a subset of $V$. The theorem doesn’t require that its span be a subset of $V$, although that must also be the case because of closure.

Neither vector in your second example is an element of the vector space $V$ in your first example (the span of those first three vectors), so this set clearly doesn’t meet the conditions of the theorem. This latter pair of vectors might well be a basis for some other space, but it’s certainly not a basis of $V$.